# Speed up multi-loop data computation in Pandas

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

Here is my question. Take the dataframe below as an example:

[image]

- The dataframe `df` has 8 columns, each of them has finite values.
- What I'm going to do:

  - a.  Loop over the dataframe by **rows**
  - b.  In each row, the value of column *B1*, *B2*, *B3*, *B4*, *B5*, *B6* will be changed to **B* x A**

Code like this:

```
 for i in range(0,len(df),1):
     col_B = ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6",]
     for j in range(len(col_B)):
         df.[col_B[j]].iloc[i] = df.[col_B[j]].iloc[i]*df.A.iloc[i]
```

In my real data which contain 224 rows and 9 columns, to loop over all these cells cost me **0:01:03**.

How to boost up the loop-over velocity in Pandas?

Any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) `DataFrame` and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print(df.filter(like='B').mul(df.A, axis=0))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B1':[4,5,6],
                   'B2':[7,8,9],
                   'B3':[1,3,5],
                   'B4':[5,3,6],
                   'B5':[7,4,3],
                   'B6':[1,3,7]})

print (df)
   A  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
0  1   4   7   1   5   7   1
1  2   5   8   3   3   4   3
2  3   6   9   5   6   3   7

print(df.filter(like='B').mul(df.A, axis=0))
   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
0   4   7   1   5   7   1
1  10  16   6   6   8   6
2  18  27  15  18   9  21
```

If need column `A` use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (pd.concat([df.A, df.filter(like='B').mul(df.A, axis=0)], axis=1))
   A  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
0  1   4   7   1   5   7   1
1  2  10  16   6   6   8   6
2  3  18  27  15  18   9  21
```

**Timings**:

`len(df)=3`:

```
In [416]: %timeit (pd.concat([df.A, df.filter(like='B').mul(df.A, axis=0)], axis=1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

In [417]: %timeit loop(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.28 ms per loop
```

`len(df)=30k`:

```
In [420]: %timeit (pd.concat([df.A, df.filter(like='B').mul(df.A, axis=0)], axis=1))
The slowest run took 4.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 3 ms per loop

In [421]: %timeit loop(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 35.6 s per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B1':[4,5,6],
                   'B2':[7,8,9],
                   'B3':[1,3,5],
                   'B4':[5,3,6],
                   'B5':[7,4,3],
                   'B6':[1,3,7]})

print (df)

df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

print (pd.concat([df.A, df.filter(like='B').mul(df.A, axis=0)], axis=1))

def loop(df):
    for i in range(0,len(df),1):
         col_B = ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6",]
         for j in range(len(col_B)):
             df[col_B[j]].iloc[i] = df[col_B[j]].iloc[i]*df.A.iloc[i]  
    return df

print (loop(df))
```